# I am trying to connect a feed to in azure devops , getting the error TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops

Getting the below error as I try to publish to artifactory
Failed to update Universal Packages tooling.
 TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from my answer?

Comment: I had same error when i had the organisation url incorrect

Answer (score 0):

> TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource

Based on your error message it should be the permission issue.

Please confirm if the user has the correct permission to publish package to the feed:

[Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops#azure-artifacts)

[image]

Besides, if you are using PAT to publish package, please check if the PAT has expired 
 and you have granted the `Packaging Read&Write` permission for the PAT. This scope is used to manage the Packages in Azure Devops:

[image]

Hope this helps.