# Upload .zip folder in Azure Artifacts Manual

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-artifacts

I am able to run this below cmd successfully but in Artifacts only empty package create with name my-first-package without any data. I am not sure what is wrong .zip deploy consist **multiple folder** and **`.dll files`** but nothing is published in the artifacts.

**Command:-**

```
az artifacts universal publish --organization  [https://org.visualstudio.com/](https://org.visualstudio.com/)  --project="my-project" --scope project --feed feed_name --name my-first-package --version 0.0.1 --description "Test Package " --path "C:\Artifacts\Deploy.zip"

{ "Description": " Package ", "ManifestId": "", "SuperRootId": "", "Version": "0.0.1" }
```

**Please advise me on this**

**Command:-**

```
C:\Artifacts> az artifacts universal publish --organization  [https://org.visualstudio.com/](https://org.visualstudio.com/)  --project="my-project" --scope project --feed feed_name --name my-first-package --version 0.0.1 --description "Test Package " --path "C:\Artifacts\Deploy.zip"
```

**Please advise me on how the Deploy .zip folder  should be published in azure artifacts**

Comment: Agree with answer from @SiddheshDesai. The package has been published succesfully as `my-first-package` shows on your feed. It won't show the package detail content for universal type feed, you need to download the package to check.

Comment: may i know if there's any update? Does the reply help? Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried publishing Azure Artifact zip with all the zip deploy files from my local machine to Azure DevOps Artifacts with CLI command like below:-

My Zipped folder contains all the appropriate files, Refer below:-

[image]

My Feed in Azure CLI command below with Feed scoped at Organizational level:-

**Command:-**

```bash
az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/orgname --feed sid24desai0738 --name testabcsilicon --version 0.0.1 --description "web zip packages" --path C:\Users\username\source\repos\WebApplication19.zip
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

The Zip package was uploaded and In order to verify the uploaded zip package, Download it like below:-

**Command:-**

```bash
az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/ --feed sid24desai0738 --name testabcsilicon --version 0.0.1 --path .
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Make sure your Azure DevOps user or the PAT token used have appropriate permissions to upload the artifacts, Refer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650047/i-am-trying-to-connect-a-feed-to-in-azure-devops-getting-the-error-tf400813-t)** and [**here**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tf400813-the-user-is-not-authorized-to-access-this-9/1573273).